# How do add include path to Eclipse project (C++, open folder mode)

Tags: c++, eclipse, build-process

I created a project by opening an already existing folder. There are some include files I need to add, otherwise Eclipse won't find references. If I right-click on the folder, I don't see the usual option I would see with a regular project. Is there a way to tell Eclipse where to look for w.r.t. include files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you see then if you do not see the usual option? There is also a way to set paths in eclipse preferences, not just the project preferences. Did you try it?

Comment: is it under window->preferences? I dont see it.

Comment: It is in Run Configurations, you can add those files there in certain compiler...